# Why does my program's memory not release?

Tags: c++, memory, deque

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    string str;
    vector<string> vec;
    Node(){};
    ~Node(){};
};
int main ()
{
    deque<Node> deq;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        Node tmp;
        tmp.vec.resize(100000);
        deq.push_back(tmp);
    }
    while(!deq.empty())
    {
        deq.pop_front();
    }
    {
        deque<Node>().swap(deq);
    }
    cout<<"releas\n";
    sleep(80000000);
    return 0;
}
```

By `top` ,I found my program's memory was about 61M, why? And it's ok if there is a copy-constructor in `Node`.I would like to know why , not how to make it correct.

gcc (GCC) 4.9.1, centos

Comment: Deleting C++ objects just makes the memory available for future allocations, it doesn't return it to the OS.

Comment: What makes you think it shouldn't be 61mb?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious His question is why it's not going down after he does the loop that pops them all out of the deque.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, `new`/`delete` and `malloc`/`realloc`/`free` arrange for more memory from the OS using [`sbrk()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk) or OS-specific-equivalent, and divide the pages up however they like to satisfy the program's allocation requests.  It's not worth the bother to try to release small pages back to the OS - too much extra overhead tracking the pages that are / are not still part of the pool, rerequesting them etc..  In low memory situations, normal caching mechanisms will allow long-unused memory pages to be swapped out of physical RAM anyway.

FWIW, GNU libC's `malloc` et al. makes an exception for particularly large requests so they can be fully released for the OS / other programs to use before program termination; quoting from [the NOTES section here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html):

> When allocating blocks of memory larger than `MMAP_THRESHOLD` bytes, the glibc `malloc()`
>          implementation allocates the memory as a private anonymous mapping
>          using `mmap`(2).  `MMAP_THRESHOLD` is 128 kB by default, but is
>          adjustable using `mallopt`(3).  Allocations performed using `mmap`(2) are
>          unaffected by the `RLIMIT_DATA` resource limit (see `getrlimit`(2)).

Comment: This is the right answer, and honestly people should google better, I think this question has been asked dozen of times.

Answer (score 0):

If container is `vector`, you can use `swap` to release memory, container is `deque`, you should use `clear` to release memory, like this:

```
int main ()
{
    deque<Node> deq;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        Node tmp;
        tmp.vec.resize(100000);
        deq.push_back(tmp);
    }
    while(!deq.empty())
    {
        deq.pop_front();
    }
    deq.clear();
    // Or, you should try to use `deque<Node>().swap(deq);`, not `local`.

    cout<<"releas\n";
    sleep(80000000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it is no use for me , and you?

Comment: This still probably won't reduce his process size, because clearing the deque won't return the memory to the OS.