# In Qt, why does setting the style sheet of a QPushButton increases my memory allocation permanently?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, memory, memory-management

I am using Visual Studio 2022, the latest ISOs for C and C++, and Qt. I have the header files and the library files linked against my solution (`.lib` files are linked to the solution and the `.dll` files are inside the directory where the executable files are).

I have worked on my project for months now. It has grown complex. I realized I have a part of my project that allocates memory in ram permanently every time it would get called. Despite it being complex, I tracked the issue to be related to setting the style sheet of `QPushButton` objects like so: `qPushButton.setStylesheet("background-color: green;")`.

Here is my minimal example:

```
#include <QtWidgets/qapplication.h>
#include <QtWidgets/QStyleFactory>
#include <QtWidgets/qdialog.h>
#include <QtWidgets/qpushbutton.h>
#include <QtWidgets/qboxlayout.h>

void test(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Init Qt
    QApplication::setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"));
    QApplication qApplication = QApplication(argc, argv);

    QDialog qDialog = QDialog(nullptr);

    QHBoxLayout qHBoxLayout = QHBoxLayout(&qDialog);
    qDialog.setLayout(&qHBoxLayout);

    QPushButton qPushButton1 = QPushButton("Button 1", &qDialog);
    QPushButton qPushButton2 = QPushButton("Button 2", &qDialog);

    qHBoxLayout.addWidget(&qPushButton1);
    qHBoxLayout.addWidget(&qPushButton2);

    QObject::connect(&qPushButton1, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]() {
        qPushButton2.setStyleSheet("");
        qPushButton1.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;");
        });
    QObject::connect(&qPushButton2, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]() {
        qPushButton1.setStyleSheet("");
        qPushButton2.setStyleSheet("background-color: green;");
        });

    qDialog.exec();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    test();
}
```

[image]

I reached to the conclusion by putting the minimal example together and by paying attention to the "Diagnostic Tools" window. The graphics show that the memory my program has allocated keep going up every time I press any button and it never goes down.

Can someone explain to me why this is the case? What would be an alternative to this that does not present this behavior? My program is to run for hours and maybe even days when I release it and cannot afford to have this behavior.

Comment: FYI: [Freeing up memory used by stylesheet in QT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65873553/7478597), [Memory leak using StyleSheet](https://forum.qt.io/topic/138262/memory-leak-using-stylesheet) (Maybe, the Qt Forum could be worth a 2nd try. I found it remarkable that a Software Engineer of The Qt Company was replying.)

Comment: What happens if you apply style sheets in a loop (say: a timeout event). Does the memory consumption grow linear or does it stop after a certain time? I must admit that I'm used to the fact that GUI applications have a horrible memory consumption but usually it reaches some peak value and than stays constant. Though, I rarely use style sheets to achieve graphical effects... (Just a matter of habit.)

Comment: I took both of your advise, read the threads and ran some more tests. The memory allocation only goes up with no way to make it go down after the style sheet is applied visually, not when the ```setStyleSheet``` function is called. Therefore, the issue is internal to Qt. I hope they look into this and fix this in the future. In the meantime, I will avoid using stylesheets in parts of my program that are meant to run for long periods of time.