# Free up memory immediately by swap trick (C++)

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, memory, vector

I have a very large vector as follows.

```
vector<vector<int>> a(100000, vector<int>(100000);
// do some work using a here
......
```

After the work is done, I use

```
vector<vector<int>>().swap(a);
```

in order to free the memory used by "a" *immediately*. I add

```
sleep(100)
```

after the swap and use "top" command to see whether memory usage is reduced immediately. But I observe that nothing has changed. What happens here?

Comment: What specifically are the symptopms of it not working? What are you measuring to see whether it worked?

Comment: How are you measuring memory? There is no guarantee C/C++ will return the virtual memory to the OS, or how long until the OS otherwise considers that memory inactive.

Comment: When you say "memory", are you talking about address space (virtual memory) or physical memory (RAM)?

Comment: The memory is freed. Do not expect to see that immediately in the Task Manager if this is how you claim that it isn't.

Comment: @Useless I used the "top" command and observed that the memory was not released. Is "top" not appropriate here?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Yes. Is the information shown in Task Manager not correct?

Comment: The information shown in Task Manager and in top is correct, but almost irrelevant, because you don't understand how process memory allocation behaves. Shrinking your vector returns memory to the process free store, but probably keeps it for later reuse instead of returning it directly to the OS.

Comment: It is correct from the point of view of Windows. Your program still has that memory. The allocator will reuse it when asked to allocate something else. It is also correct from the C++ object model, 100000 calls to `~std::vector<int>()` occured, and 10000000000 `int`s ceased to be.

Comment: @yicepeh969 As has already been pointed out, the information shown in Task Manager reflects information the OS has about your running process. The sort of memory allocation that `std::vector` uses by default (`new` and `delete`) is typically handled by a runtime layer inside your process, not by the OS directly. Just because you returned a bunch of memory to the memory allocator that `new` and `delete` use underneath doesn't mean that memory allocator also returned it to the OS. It just means the memory allocator may start handing out bits of this memory again next time you allocate something…

Comment: There's a similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29529288/212858) - I can't find a better duplicate immediately, but it has more detail than fits in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

To immediately clear vector out from the memory you should do :

```
v.clear();
v.shrink_to_fit();
```

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit): "It is a non-binding request to reduce `capacity()` to `size()`. **It depends on the implementation whether the request is fulfilled.**"

Comment: That doesn't change anything at all (swapping with temporary empty vector was the way to do it before shrink_to_fit() was introduced), but memory still doesn't have to be returned to OS immediately.

Comment: @Aconcagua sure, but i didn't know that author meaned OS memory by "memory".

Comment: @Aconcagua the question had been edited after my answer

Comment: Ah, missed that, sorry. That's the problem with those essential edits, invalidating previously totally fine answers...

Answer (score 2):

It should work you might have error elsewhere in the code or you don't judge correctly whether the memory is freed.

You could make the deallocation more general - so it'll work on anything without performing any unnecessary operations in the swap. Swap consists of three moves. You can achieve the same result with a move and default reinitialization.

```
   {auto x=std::move(a);a={};}
```

`x` steals `a`'s memory and gets destroyed after leaving the scope. The `a={};` isn't be necessary in most cases but according to standart after `moving from` object is allowed to be in a rather weird state.

Comment: This is equivalent to `std::exchange(a, {})`

Comment: @Kerndog - indeed. Though, honestly, currently I'd prefer the longer version less near version. If there is a bug in the code compilation and you find it in `std::exchange`... till `concepts` are online templates can be bothersome.

Comment: A bug in `std::vector`? I don't follow

Comment: @Kerndog I mean about general deallocation method. But for vector it is indeed unnecessary.